# need information on a deleted SSRS report

Tags: ssrs

In SSRS, once a report is deleted, the ItemPath no longer appears in the ExecutionLog because the Catalog no longer has the report information.  I can track down the ReportID, but I can't find anywhere with the history of the report name.

Is there anywhere I could find the name and path of the deleted report?  If not, any suggestions on how to best stash the information moving forward?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to get the information restore a backup taken prior to removing the report into a different environment and get it from there.

Answer (score -1):

To see what SQL Server knows about your report you can try:

```
select * from Reportserver.dbo.Catalog where name='xxx'

select * from Reportserver.dbo.Catalog where name='project name'
```

Comment: The information has been removed from the Catalog.